# How to block duplicate values while inserting value into an array?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

How to prevent duplicate values during insert record into an array using angular6+

**PARENTCOMPONENT.HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-left:30px;margin-top:30px;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Posts" name="post" [(ngModel)]="post" #clearText>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="AddServer(post)" 
style="margin-left:30px;margin-top:10px;" (blur) = "clearText.value = ''">Click</button>

<app-child [childPost]="parentPosts"></app-child>
```

**PARENTCOMPONENT.TS:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

post = '';
parentPosts: any[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  AddServer(post)
  {
    this.parentPosts.push(post);
    console.log(post);
  }
}
```

**CHILDCOMPONENT.HTML:**

```
<div style="margin-left: 30px; margin-top:10px;" *ngFor="let p of childPost">
  <p>{{p}}</p>
</div>
```

**CHILDCOMPONENT.TS:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() childPost: any[] = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Hi guys the above code was insert data from parent component to child component using textbox values and button in that PARENCOMPONENT.TS code what i need is during the time of pushing value into an array the values must be unique if i post repeated value it throws an alert or error message the value was already inserted like that so please kindly help me to resolve this....

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) data structure that will omit duplicate Insertions which is better then having an extra loop to verify if it's already in the array and then omit it.

```js
parentPosts: Set = new Set();


// then use it like
this.parentPosts.add(post); // if post already exists it'll just not add it
```

Comment: Hi Andrei it throws an error could you please explain elaborately

Comment: I think you have to specify the type of objects. So, as I see your **parentPosts** array was of type **any**. Please try to add the type: **parentPosts: Set<any> = new Set()**. Notes: A Set is storing only **keys** not **key-value** pairs. Eg: `let set = new Set(['APPLE', 'ORANGE', 'MANGO']);`

Answer (score 1):

Test if it contains it first

```
if (!this.parentPosts.includes(post)) {
  this.parentPosts.push(post);
}
```

Comment: Yep Thanks for giving this information Adrian it's perfectly working.....

Comment: That's what the accept answer and upvote buttons are for.